# Swift & FCM : How to get push notification data when switching from Background to Foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm configuring push notifications in Swift. So far I have 3 scenarios.

1 - App In Foreground
In the foreground, I think I did everything correct cus I did receive the push notification data.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        print("userNotificationCenter willPresent")
        let content = notification.request.content
        
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
        
    }
```

2 - User clicks on the Push Notification banner
This is also working fine.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("userNotificationCenter didReceive")
       defer {
           completionHandler()
       }
       guard response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier else {
           return
       }
        
        let content = response.notification.request.content
        
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    }
```

**3 - App in background, then the user gets into the app**
In this scenario, the push notification arrives at the user's phone. But, instead of clicking on the push notification itself, they get into the app. And I can't fetch any info from the push notification

Could anyone help on how to configure the 3rd scenario? Thank you.

Comment: @Paulw11 Are you 100% sure about this?

Comment: Actually, they have added a new API - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649520-getdeliverednotifications If the user clears the notifications before your app returns to the foreground then they are lost, but if they are still in the Notification Center you can get them this way.  Notifications are not guaranteed delivery and you should not rely on them as the only way to update your app

Comment: I heard it's only available on ios 15. But I will check it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you need to consider [applicationState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/state)

> UIApplication.State

```
//AppDelegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
    case .active:
        print("Received push message from APNs on Foreground")
    case .background:
        print("Received push message from APNs on Background")
    case .inactive:
        print("Received push message from APNs back to Foreground")
    }
}
```

When the app is background to foreground, `UIApplication.State` is `inactive`

inactive is '**The app is running in the foreground but is not receiving events.**'

thus I think the best way to do the behavior you want is to write it yourself.

for example,

```
//AppDelegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
    case .active:
        print("Received push message from APNs on Foreground")
    case .background:
        print("Received push message from APNs on Background")
    case .inactive:
        print("Received push message from APNs back to Foreground")

        guard let nav = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
              let currentVC = nav.viewControllers.last else {return}

        if currentVC is 'youWantViewController' { //if you want ViewController, use notification post
            let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: K.Event.pushRequest)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil)
        } else { //move to you want ViewController
           let vc = 'yourViewController'()
           root.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

I hope it will be of help.