# Swift & Push Notification : application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) does not get called

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm configuring push notification is swift. But I noticed that the method below doesn't get called for some reason. Could you tell me why? Are there any necessary setups I should have done? Thank you

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Received data message: \(userInfo)")
        
        let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: K.Event.someEvent)
        
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
```

Comment: How did you send the notification via `APNs`?

Comment: List the steps you have taken for your FCM implementation.

Comment: Besides, you need more lines of code than the ones shown above.

Comment: This is what did for push notification overall. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627846/swift-fcm-how-to-get-push-notification-data-when-switching-from-background-t?noredirect=1#comment123071144_69627846

Comment: @Itachi I use FCM. Do you have any useful sample code I can check out?

Answer (score 1):

need [post](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415812-post)

> NotificationCenter.default.post(name:object:)

```
//AppDelegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable:Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Received data message: \(userInfo)")

    let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: K.Event.pushRequest)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name, object: nil) //or your object

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

also, you need to [addObserver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver) in UIViewController

> addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)

```
//your viewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: K.Event.pushRequest)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(handleNotification),
                                           name: name, 
                                           object: nil) //or your object
}

@objc func handleNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("notification")
}
```